# Construct a function-callable object from an RPN at a runtime

Tags: c++, function, rpn

I'm designing a program that would perform certain operations on a streaming data.
Operations are defined by the RPN (reverse polish notation) expressions provided at runtime. Data is being streamed from a file source, one fixed size portion at a time. Operations reference some of the currently input portion of data, like `data[1]`. The program applies the same operation to all input portions (and streams out the results).

It is quite easy to implement an RPN parser that operates on numbers and arithmetic operation to give the result. However, using such an implementation would imply re-parsing the RPN for every data portion.

What I would like to implement is to build somehow an object that would hold the once parsed RPN implementation based on the alphabet of elementary operations on data, where the program would provide the input data (or fill-in the inputs), invoke the object's `operator()` to obtain and output the result.

How would one implement such a class (a `callable expression`) and construct such an object using the 'non-modern' C++ (no `C++11` or `C++14`)?

Comment: that's a very very simple parser.  look up any type of parsing tutorial and it's usually an example.  This sounds like homework

Comment: @Alejandro I think there should be a tree involved, storing the operations at branching points and operands (constants and data references) at terminal leaves. The functional tree must be constructed once, and called every time.

Comment: @AhmedMasud The question is not about parser. The parser is not needed. A class that can store the parsed RPN in functional form is needed, so the object can be called to obtain the result.

Comment: This is not a place for people to do your work for you. If you have any specific problems while implementing what you ask, you should come back and ask for help with those instead.

Comment: well then if you have it already parsed then triggering on each token is easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since its RPN, the operations can be modeled as a sequence of transformations of a stack. Loading one input portion on the stack and then performing your operations in order would do the trick. No tree needed, it's implicit in the order of operations. No need to reparse either, it would indeed be a sequence of operations (functions or functors) rather then a sequence of symbols denoting operations.

I would choose a functor since I like storing references or pointers to objects better than storing references or pointers to functions. You implement that as a class having an overloaded operator () that does the required stack transformation (like multiplying the two top elements if it's a multiplication functor).

[image: Ancient device working that way...]

**Above: Ancient device working that way...**

As to what is stored on the stack and what isn't:

- At first your operands are stored in a queue matching the order of input
- Your operator objects, result of parsing once and never changing, are stored separately in an operator queue.
- Applying the 'get' operator will transfer one operand from the queue to the operand stack

So e.g. if you want to compute

```
sin (3 + 4) / (5 + 6)
```

your operand queue is:

```
[start] 3 4 5 6 [end]
```

Your operator object queue (it contains pointers to functors, not symbols, each functor has only one instance, but is referenced possibly multiple times) is:

```
[start] &getFunctor &getFunctor &addFunctor &sinFunctor &getFunctor &getFunctor &addFunctor &divideFunctor [begin]
```

Your operand stack starts out emptpy:

```
[top][bottom]
```

Applying the operator queue will give you subsequently:

```
(get)    [top] 3 [bottom]
(get)    [top] 3 4 [bottom]
(add)    [top] 7 [bottom]
(sin)    [top] 0.657 [bottom]
(get)    [top] 5  0.657 [bottom]
(get)    [top] 5 6  0.657 [bottom]
(add)    [top] 11  0.657[bottom]
(divide) [top] 0.0597 [bottom]
```

If you then want to apply exactly the same operations to e.g.

```
[start]10 20 30 40[end]
```

just replace the operand queue (or let the start pointer of you operand queue point to the next "chunk" of your operand file, and again run your operator queue against this new sequence of operands.

Note that the operator queue, as said, doesn't hold operator symbols, but pointers to ready-to-go function objects that will do their thing as soon as you call them, without reparsing or regenerating code.

So if you have lots of data:

```
[start of file]3 4 5 6   10 20 30 40   -1 -10 15 80 ...[end of file]
```

You just keep applying the same operator queue and everything will work.

Comment: So you propose to build a class that is essentially a stack of objects that are allowed to modify the stack themselves? That's neat. However, I can't yet see how you can have it not reconstructed at every iteration, since applying an RPN is actually wiping the corresponding stack.

Comment: Pointers to your operator functor objects are not on the stack but in a fixed queue. They are parsed and compiled only once and then applied to subsequent chunks of data, each chunk holding a new set of operands. I've put an example in the answer.